# Increasing multivariate function: interpreting the definition

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, functions

I have doubts on how to interpret the following definition of $L$-increasing function.

Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}\equiv \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the real line.

Let $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^L$ be the $L$-fold Cartesian product for a positive integer $L$.

Let $\mathcal{U}\equiv \mathcal{U}_1 \times ... \times \mathcal{U}_L \subseteq \bar{\mathbb{R}}^L$ with $ \mathcal{U}_l\subseteq \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ $\forall l \in \{1,...,L\}$.

**Definition** $F: \mathcal{U}\rightarrow ...$ is $L$-increasing if $\forall u{'}, u{''}\in \mathcal{U}$ with $u{'}\leq u{''}$ component-wise

$$
\text{Vol}_{F}(u{'}, u{''})\equiv \sum_{u\in \text{Vrt}(u{'}, u{''})}\text{sgn}_{u{'}, u{''}}(u)F(u)\geq 0
$$
 where

- $\text{Vrt}(u{'}, u{''})\equiv \{u\in \mathcal{U} \text{: } u_l\in \{u_l{'}, u_l{''}\} \text{ }\forall l\in \{1,...,L\}\}$
- $\text{sgn}_{u{'}, u{''}}(u)\equiv \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{ if $u_l=u_l{'}$ for an even number of $l\in \{1,...,L\}$}\\
  -1 & \text{ if $u_l=u_l{'}$ for an odd number of $l\in \{1,...,L\}$}\\
  \end{cases}$
- $\text{Vol}_{F}(u{'}, u{''})$ is the $F$-volume of the $L$-box $[u_1{'}, u_1{''}]\times ... \times [u_L{'}, u_L{''}]$ and the elements of the set $\text{Vrt}(u{'}, u{''})$ are the vertices of the $L$-box

**Question** I am confused on the last part of the definition: "$\text{Vol}_{F}(u{'}, u{''})$ is the $F$-volume of the $L$-box $[u_1{'}, u_1{''}]\times ... \times [u_L{'}, u_L{''}]$ and the elements of the set $\text{Vrt}(u{'}, u{''})$ are the vertices of the $L$-box". Could you help me to understand why $\text{Vol}_{F}(u{'}, u{''})$ is a volume?

I have tried to picture an example for $L=2$

[image]

The green area is $F$.

Suppose $u'\equiv (2,2)$ and $u''\equiv (4,3)$. Hence, $\text{Vrt}(u{'}, u{''})\equiv \{u', u'', A, B\}$ with $A\equiv (u'_1, u''_2)$ and $B\equiv (u''_1, u'_2)$. Thus, we get

$$
\text{Vol}_{F}(u{'}, u{''})\equiv 1*F(u')+1*F(u'')-1*F(A)-1*F(B)
$$

Why this is a volume? It looks like just the difference between points' heights.